# how to get individual associated id's of listview elements when clicked

Tags: android, hashmap, listactivity

I am displaying an arraylist through a listactivity. Also, i have associated id's with these arraylist elements which i can get together in a hashmap maybe. But the problem is i want to obtain that particular id of the element when it is clicked. How to achieve that. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that worked for me is as follows. Hope it maybe useful for others.
I had the data in Arraylist> testdata. I passed it like this :-

```
this.setListAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(Grammar_tab_start.this, testdata ,
                       .layout.tab_single_item, new String[] { "module_name"},
                        new int[] { R.id.from}));
  ListView lv = getListView();

   to single list item on click
  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id)

  {

        Log.i("check","Module item clicked");
  HashMap<String,String> pos=(HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position) ;

  Log.i("check","----" + position + "id" + id +"actual is "+ pos.get("module_id"));
         }
```

I used the lv.getItemAtPosition() function to retrieve the whole object that was clicked. And then took th eid part from it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the id based on the clicked position if you an implementation of the `getItemId(position)` method in your adapter. The id you return here will be the `long id` argument in the `onListItemClick(...)` method of your `ListActivity`.

`getItemId(int position)` is a member of the `ArrayAdapter` class. The `ListActivity` will call that function from the adapter of your`ListView`. All you have to do is to provide the implementation, the rest will work out just fine.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getItemId(int)

Comment: That looks like a feasible solution. Thnx. Where exactly am i suppose to create this function. In the same class where i am making its object? And how will i get the id to be returned in the function? It would really help if you could provide a prototype for that function.

Comment: i get the concept. What i am having problem with is how to write its body. I mean, how to access the element that was clicked and also where exactly do i have to write this function. Consider i have a  hashmap HashMap<String,String> m ,having the texts and id's . Now how will i know which one is clicked.

Comment: Implement getItem(position) too, and use it in getView(...). In getItem() you will return the item at the given position from your map, or an array or whatever. In getItemId() you will get the same element if you use getItem(position). And from the object getItem() returned you can return the ID. I suggest you to read the adapters documentation if you want to know any more. There are a lot of examples in the android SDK and on the developer page regarding ListViews

Answer (score 0):

```
      ListView lv = getListView();
      lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
            long pos=lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
            //do your stuff here


     }

});
```

if you are using your own ArrayAdapter, you can implement the getItem(position) method..

Comment: thanx for that. However, My problem is how to implement that function exactly? Can you provide some samole code for it. I have a HashMap containing the texts and id's. I have shown them in a list view. Now how will know in this function which element was clicked?

Comment: does every item in your list on click does the same action ?

Comment: yes. I get the corresponding id and pass it to the nect activity through intent. Thats all.

Comment: on onItemClick.. you are trying to get the id of the list item  selected.. if I am not wrong

Comment: Well that didnt worked as it gave me normal id only, but it gave me the idea to get the whole item  ie lv.getItemAtPosition(pos) and then i stored it also in a hashmap and the then retrieved the corrs id. Thnax for the direction anyways.

Comment: you are welcome.. ( you can edit and accept the answer if it was useful for you.. it would fetch reputation points for both of us and will give others the correct solution )- Thanks